# Drivers for Lenovo Thinkpad S540 Touchpad (erratic mouse cursor)

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad

The touch-pad on the Thinkpad S540 is extremely erratic (the cursor often jumps when right-clicking, making it extremely difficult to right click anything, and even left-click sensitivity seems to be very poor). I am using `Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS`. The touchpad is an "all in one" variety with no separate left and right buttons, but having them built in to the pad area.

Is there anywhere I can obtain better touchpad drivers? or generally anything else
I can do to improve the mouse behavior?

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to help, at least somewhat:

Create the following config file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-thinkpad-touchpad.conf (create xorg.conf.d directory if it doesn't exist):

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad"
        MatchProduct "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
        Driver "synaptics"
        # fix touchpad resolution
        Option "VertResolution" "100"
        Option "HorizResolution" "65"
        # increment noise cancellation factor
        Option "HorizHysteresis" "50"
        Option "VertHysteresis" "50"
EndSection
```

Not sure if there are a better set of tweaks out there...

See also:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1042069
- http://fully-faltoo.com/2013/07/20/lenovo-touchpad/
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.phpTouchpad_Synaptics#Buttonless_TouchPads_.28aka_ClickPads.29
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad