# How do I disable the TouchPad on a laptop, but keep mouse buttons active?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo

I want to disable the touchpad of my Lenovo x240. If I use the settings GUI the mouse buttons get disabled, too.

How can I disable the touchpad mouse cursor movement, and keep the mouse buttons active?

Related, but I want to disable mouse movements completely:

[Drivers for Lenovo Thinkpad S540 Touchpad (erratic mouse cursor)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393475/drivers-for-lenovo-thinkpad-s540-touchpad-erratic-mouse-cursor/429708)

I use Ubuntu 14.04 with xserver-xorg-input-synaptics version 1.7.4

Comment: The `synclient` parameters are documented here: http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html

Comment: Related: askubuntu.com/questions/370505/how-to-use-trackpoint-but-keep-touchpad-disabled-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e531

Answer (score 2):

Open gedit and copy-paste the following lines into it:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This script disables the touchpad without disabling buttons by setting Hysteresis
# to an impossible value.

############
# Warning! #
############
# If you have a touchpad with no "Physical" buttons but have to tap the corners 
# of your touchpad to simulate physical buttons, put a "#" sign in front of the next
# 4 lines!

synclient LTCornerButton=1
#synclient LBCornerButton=0
synclient RTCornerButton=3
#synclient RBCornerButton=0


# Set PalmDetect on: Needed if the before lines are commented away,
# Doesn't do any harm if they're not
synclient PalmDetect=1

synclient HorizHysteresis=10000 
synclient VertHysteresis=10000

# Disable all other touchpad features
synclient VertEdgeScroll=0
synclient HorizEdgeScroll=0
synclient CornerCoasting=0
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
synclient TouchpadOff=2
synclient LockedDrags=0
synclient TapButton1=0
synclient TapButton2=0
synclient TapButton3=0
synclient CircularPad=0
```

Then save it as `/usr/local/bin/DisableTouchPad.sh`

In a terminal type:

```
chmod a+xr /usr/local/bin/DisableTouchPad.sh
```

To activate it type:

```
DisableTouchPad.sh
```

and test whether this works.

To make this change permanent, go to the dash, open "Startup Applications", click add, in the command type: `/usr/local/bin/DisableTouchPad.sh` and in the Name and Comment type anything that will remind you what this was about.  Click add again.

**Presto: a disabled touchpad with the buttons still enabled!**

Comment: Somehow the above script does nothing. I pasted the output of `synclient -l` here: http://pastebin.com/ecGD1XmV. If I run your above script I get: `Property for 'UpDownScrolling' not available. Skipping.
Property for 'LeftRightScrolling' not available. Skipping.`

Comment: Mmmh, I can see that the output above is the output after you've run the script and it has disabled a lot already (which is what you want) but your touchpad driver doesn't allow all parameters to be changed....
Can you try the following: 
`synclient MinSpeed 0` and `synclient MaxSpeed 0`
Does that leave your buttons intact and stop the rest of the movement?

Comment: I did `synclient MinSpeed=0`and `synclient MaxSpeed=0` but nothing changes. The touchpad works like before.

Comment: Here is the diff of `synclient -l` before and after your disable script. http://pastebin.com/zF9G8QLH

Comment: that does not include the synclient Min and MaxSpeed above... (but it doesn't help anyway) Let me test an bit and I'll get back to you...

Comment: OK. Here is one with the parameters your touchpad displays:
To properly test, **disable the script in the autostart, log out and log in again**

Comment: Please keep a mouse handy!  
Then type: `synclient HorizHysteresis=10000` and `synclient VertHysteresis=10000` **report back**

Comment: The bounty period is over anyway, so you won't have to give your points to me...  Upvoting my answer will at least give me *some* credit for all the work I put in here... :/

Comment: thank you for your work. I up voted your answer and I updated it. The script was missing some "synclient" strings. The touchpad is disabled now, and one button works. But Middle- or RightButton still does not work. I looked at the launchpad site of the xserver-xorg-input-synaptics package. There are 40 open bugs. I guess it won't work with the the default version shipped with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thanks ! I got it working on my 16.04 box. Really need this feature :)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in a terminal:

```
xinput list
```

You will get an output that looks like this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_1.3M             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

It displays all the input devices connected. Note that they all have an id. Since 12 is the id for my touchpad, running the following command will disable it.

```
xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 0
```

Just change to `xinput set-prop <<ID OF DEVICE>> "Device Enabled" 0`

This is taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-the-touchpad).

Comment: This method will also disable the mouse buttons and hence is not useful. `synclient TouchpadOff=0` can be used to achieve the same as above.

Comment: @Philip I am sorry, your answer does not help. This disables the touchpad and the mouse buttons. The mouse buttons are just areas on the touchpad on the thinkpad x240. I ask myself how can anyone work with this device.. I use an external thinkpad keyboard now. But that's no good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a Lenovo T440s with a similar touchpad. I haven't disabled it myself (although I prefer to use the trackpoint), but I used [this blog by Who-t](http://who-t.blogspot.nl/2014/03/xorg-synaptics-support-for-lenovo-t440.html) to configure mine. On that page it says:

> If you don't like touchpads at all and prefer to use the trackstick only, use `Option "TouchpadOff" "1"`. This will disable everything but physical clicks on the touchpad.

The place to put this option in is a `Section "InputClass"` in a file `etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, which you could name `80-fix-thinkpad-touchpad.conf` or something similar. See the aforementioned web site for examples.